# Deduce type of Compare for std::set from constructor arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, stdset

I wanna write simpler syntax when declaring std::set with custom compare:

```
auto s = std::set({1,3,7,9,2,4},[](int a,int b){return a>b;});
```

but it does not work out of the box. CLang produces:

```
/Users/kyb/devel/untitled3/main.cpp:13:14: error: ambiguous deduction for template arguments of 'set'
    auto s = set({1,3,7,9,2,4},[](int a,int b){return a>b;});
             ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/set:531:5: note: candidate function [with _Key = int, _Compare = (lambda at /Users/kyb/devel/untitled3/main.cpp:13:32), _Allocator = std::__1::allocator<int>]
    set(initializer_list<value_type> __il, const value_compare& __comp = value_compare())
    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/set:547:5: note: candidate function [with _Key = int, _Compare = std::__1::less<int>, _Allocator = (lambda at /Users/kyb/devel/untitled3/main.cpp:13:32)]
    set(initializer_list<value_type> __il, const allocator_type& __a)
    ^
1 error generated.
```

There is a trick - invade deduction guide:

```
namespace std::__1{
    template<typename T, typename Compare> set(initializer_list<T> il, const Compare&comp) -> set<T,Compare>;
}
```

which produces warning:

```
warning: inline namespace reopened as a non-inline namespace
```

I believe there is a way to do that in more clean way.

clang --version:

```
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
/V/l/n/new-diag-commands ❯❯❯
```

Comment: Okay this? `auto com = [](int a, int b) {return a > b; };
   std::set<int, decltype(com)> s({1,3,7,9,2,4 }, com);`. It will compile even with clang-7:https://godbolt.org/z/Zc9WxU

Comment: [Works for me](https://godbolt.org/z/YvVEPz) for msvc clang and gcc. Did you enabled C++17 which allows this? Voting to close as "can't reproduce".

Comment: @MarekR As pointed out in my answer this is a clang defect in versions prior to Clang 9.

Comment: @dfri [Works with clang 7 fails on clang 6](https://godbolt.org/z/rAPLeW).

Comment: @MarekR That is weird, [according to wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jFdXVMt75fLfMiIE) it is fails on all clang version prior to clang 9.

Comment: This must be some missconfiguration on one of the sites. Versions are printed correctly: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/tWjSqG) and [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ot8LwwTknziK8Pm2) so most probably library headers are shared by different versions of clang.

Comment: @MarekR It seems that godbolt, weirdly enough, [makes use of GCC STL headers (?!) also for clang](https://godbolt.org/z/j1pup-): `/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.3.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8.3.0 ...`, whereas [wandbox explicitly contains a reference to a clang8 library header](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wZyiiOQvTR7YtIHJ) in its error message (`/opt/wandbox/clang-8.0.0/include/c++/v1/set:564:5: error ...`). To return to the original discussion: a clang defect (most likely) in versions prior to Clang 9. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find a relevant LLVM bug report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I believe there is a way to do that in more clean way.

Your code snippet above should not be rejected by clang, as is governed by [[associative.reqmts]/15](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/associative.reqmts#15)<sup>1</sup> [**emphasis** mine]:

> A deduction guide for an associative container shall not participate
> in overload resolution if any of the following are true:
>
> - (15.1) It has an `InputIterator` template parameter and a type that does not qualify as an input iterator is deduced for that parameter.
> - (15.2) It has an `Allocator` template parameter and **a type that does not qualify as an allocator is deduced for that parameter**.
> - (15.3) It has a Compare template parameter and a type that qualifies as an allocator is deduced for that parameter.

As of Clang 9, this has been corrected.

---

<sub>[1] [N4659: March 2017 post-Kona working draft/C++17 DIS](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/).</sub>

Comment: Yes. I have noticed that a moment ago.